# Garbage value printed in std::set

Tags: c++, stl, set

I wrote the simple program below to find out the single character that is different between the two input strings `s` and `t`:

```
class Solution {
public:
    char findTheDifference(string s, string t) {
        std::set<char> set1;
        std::set<char> set2;
        int i=0;

        while(s[i]!='\0') {
            set1.insert(s[i]);
            i++;
        }

        i=0;
        while(t[i]!='\0') {
            set2.insert(t[i]);
            i++;
        }

        std::set<char>::iterator it;
        for(it=set1.begin(); it!=set1.end(); it++)
            cout<<*it;
        cout<<"\n";
        for(it=set2.begin(); it!=set2.end(); it++)
            cout<<*it;
        cout<<"\n";

        std::set<char> v;
        std::set_difference(set1.begin(), set1.end(), set2.begin(), set2.end(), std::inserter(v, v.end()));
        cout<<*(v.begin());

        return *(v.begin());
    }
};
```

While I have apparently done everything alright, I get the output as below:

```
abcd
abcde
\x00
```

And the `char` value returned by the function is `\x00`.  My question is, **from where is this garbage value (`\x00`) getting printed and returned?**

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `v` is empty (and therefore `*(v.begin())` exhibits undefined behavior). There are no elements that are present in `set1` but absent in `set2`. You likely want to use `std::set_symmetric_difference`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program invokes UB because all elements from *set2* are present in *set1* and there are no elements in *v* after the *std::set_difference* call.

From the *cpp.reference* [std::set_difference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference) page:

```
template< class InputIt1, class InputIt2, class OutputIt >
OutputIt set_difference(InputIt1 first1, InputIt1 last1,
                        InputIt2 first2, InputIt2 last2,
                        OutputIt d_first);
```

> Copies the elements from the sorted range [first1, last1) which are
>   not found in the sorted range [first2, last2) to the range beginning
>   at d_first.

---

There are some other tips:

1) It is better to make the arguments *const references*.

2) You can construct *set*s from *string*s directly using range constructor.

3) You might print *set*s without cycles using *copy* and *ostream_iterator*s.

Comment: Yeah, gotcha! :)  Thank you.  I will accept the answer once I am able to.

Answer (score 1):

By doing

```
 cout<<*(v.begin());
```

without checking

```
 if(v.begin() != v.end())
```

, you are risking your program with **undefined behavior**, as `begin() == end()` when a container is **empty**.